# Django JsonResponse not returning serialized data

Tags: json, django, ajax, django-views

Why JsonResponce not able to serialized the data, i think I'm getting this error because of **for x in cart_obj.products.all()**
**Error:**

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} 
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable



def cart_json_view(request):    # defined for ajax
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.create_cart_or_get_cart(request)
    products = [{
        "id": x.id,
        "url": x.get_absolute_url(),
        "name": x.name,
        "price": x.price
    } for x in cart_obj.products.all()]
    cart_data = {"products": products, "subtotal": cart_obj.subtotal, "total": cart_obj.total}
    return JsonResponse(cart_data)
```

Comment: is one of the `.subtotal` and `.total` a method? remember using () when calling a method.

Comment: @Alvi15 No these are not methods but i used them in signals for calculation.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Are you sure you're pointing to the "correct" problem?

Comment: @Alvi15 the error i mentioned above is the exact what i am getting, & prob is correct too

Answer (score 0):

need to convert cart_dat(python dictionary) to text add this line

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
.
.
.
return JsonResponse(json.loads(serialize('json', cart_data)), safe=False)
```

Comment: @RahulVerma  try to serialize https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Comment: i am new to django so can you tell me what exactly i have to do with my code.

Comment: now i am getting this error `concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`